# Mongoid date changes once model is populated

Tags: datetime, mongoid

When I put a date into mongoid it comes out one hour earlier than what I put in...
Is this a bug or am I just out of date or doing something wrong?

It fails on the first date comparison.

```
require 'mongoid'

class RawVote
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :created_at, type: DateTime
end


describe "Possible mongoid bug" do

  it "should have the same date as what I put in" do
    date = DateTime.parse("Sat Oct 15 22:27:17 +0000 2011")
    vote = RawVote.new(created_at: date)
    vote2 = RawVote.new(created_at: vote.created_at)

    vote.created_at.should == date
    vote2.created_at.should == date

    vote.nil?.should == true
  end
end
```

Comment: have you resolved this issue? I am experiencing this too...

Answer (score 0):

I have had weird experiences using DateTime with mongoid, been more stable for me to use `Time`.  Also you can also include `Mongoid::Timestamps::Created` instead of defining the field.

One thing to note about Mongoid, is that it currently truncates milliseconds when persisting to the db.  So that also could be causing you some weirdness -- but not sure why you are losing an hour